# Is it good to store all data in vuex or redux?

Tags: vue.js, redux, vuex, state-management

Is holding data in store reduce performance?
For example we have a application in vue, I get customer data from server by api.
and store it in vuex and I can set some filters to get filtered data.
Here is my vuex's state.

```
export const state = () => ({
    allCustomers: [],
    hasError: false,
    loading: false,
    searchForm: {
        name: "",
        nationalCode: "",
        mobile: ""
    },
    filterForm: {
        minAge: "",
        maxAge: "",
        minVisit: "",
        maxVisit: "",
        gender: ""
    },
    tagForm: {
        visitTag: "",
        serviceTag: ""
    }
});
```

My request code to get data is in actions part:

```
export const actions = {
    async getCustomer({ commit, state }, API) {
        commit(`${ActionsTypes.CHANGE_HAS_ERROR}`, false);
        commit(`${ActionsTypes.CHANGE_LOADING}`, true);
        commit(`${ActionsTypes.CLEAR_ARRAY}`);
        try {
            const {
                data: { data }
            } = await API.get("api/admin/customer", {
                params: setParams({ ...state.searchForm, ...state.filterForm, ...state.tagForm })
            });
            data.map(item =>
                commit(`${ActionsTypes.CHANGE_ALL_CUSTOMER}`, new Customer(item))
            );
        } catch (err) {
            commit(`${ActionsTypes.CHANGE_HAS_ERROR}`, true);
        }
        commit(`${ActionsTypes.CHANGE_LOADING}`, false);
    }
};
```

I can store these data in local data of component and pass it down through child components.
But I want to know is it good to hold all data in vuex.
I know it is easy to hold them in local data, but I want to have one pattern in all my code.
And my main question is that, Is storing data in vuex reduce performance? and this is not only about vue, react and redux is too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think using Vuex as you described is a problem. If you really need to have the data stored somewhere (vuex or components) it will have to use memory space anyway.

I prefer using Vuex for large applications since it allows me to compartmentalize the data and have it structured in a way that is easier to understand and more organized. Also, an added benefit is the lifecycle the data needs to go through in order to be stored in the state via actions and mutations, which improves the way a team interacts with the state and encourages following a process instead of editing the state directly.

The approach of passing data through components also works. However, as the app grows you'll need to keep passing data to your children components and passing objects with a complex structure can render your components difficult to maintain because you end up passing a huge object as a prop instead of multiple simple props.

So it's up to you. From a performance perspective I haven't had problems with Vuex and large datasets, but there are ways to improve Vuex performance if your app grows too much, like this: https://itnext.io/vue-js-app-performance-optimization-part-3-lazy-loading-vuex-modules-ed67cf555976